# Azure data factory parsing xml in copy activity

Tags: string, azure, parsing, xml-parsing, azure-data-factory

I am using azure data factory to have a soap API connection data to be transferred to snowflake. I understand that snowflake has to have the data in variant column or csv or we need to have intermediate storage in azure to finally land the data in snowflake. the problem I faced is the data from api is a string within that there is xml data. so when i put the data in blob storage, its a string. how do I avoid this and have the proper columns while putting the data ?

[image: mapping in azure data factory copy activity]

[image: The data in blob storage is a string]
over here, the column is read as string. is there a way to parse it into their respective rows ? I tried to put the collection reference, it still does not recognize individual columns. Any input is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could you share the structure of XML data

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<ExtractDataResponse xmlns="https://www.rivosafeguard.com/ws">
<ExtractDataResult><DocumentElement> <DataTable> <someid>123757</someid> <someotherid>241309</someotherid> <DateOccurred>2020-02-05T00:00:00+00:00</DateOccurred> </DataTable> </DocumentElement></ExtractDataResult>
</ExtractDataResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: you could use this iin a xml file.

Comment: Switch to advanced editor in mapping

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to Advanced editor in Mapping section of copy activity. I took the sample data and repro'd this. Below are the steps.

[image]
Img:1 Source dataset preview

In mapping section of copy activity,

- Click **Import Schema**
- Switch to **Advanced editor** .
- Give the collection reference value.

[image]
Img:2 Mapping settings

Comment: thanks for this. although I have a different problem. 
the xml data is enclosed with in string

This approach wont help

Comment: What is the error you are getting in this approach

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1179147/how-to-parse-a-xml-enclosed-within-a-string-in-azu
This is what I was looking for. There was no error. but the data is enclosed within double quotes